# C# get results from windows services

Tags: c#, windows, service

Good morning every body.

I have developing a C# WinForms simple aplication to manage "Apache" windows service, i can start, stop and other operations.

My Scenario:

- I open the apache config file and change any line, i made it  to causes error configuration (i know it).
- When i try start Apache service, this cant start, because the config file syntax is incorrect (i know it).
- The message error from the services is registered in Windows Events Viewer (i know it).
- I want get this message in my C# WinForms Application, it is posible?

My code:

```
public void ManageService(string serviceName, int Operation)
        {
            ServiceController sc = new ServiceController();
            sc.ServiceName = serviceName;
            try
            {
                switch (Operation)
                {
                    case 1: sc.Stop(); ; break;
                    case 2: sc.Start(); break;
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {

            }
        }
```

How to modify this code to catch messages from the apache service.

PD. Sorry if my english is bery bad ;).

Comment: Have you tried capturing the exception in the catch and return the message to the caller?

Comment: @Karen Payne, i tried with e.Message in catch, but this never call,

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not a answer per-say but don't know how to place this into a comment. Note the use of WaitForStatus and also a property for error messages. This is fairly bare-bones.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace Revenue.Common.Utility
{
    public class WindowsServices
    {
        private string _ErrorMessage;
        public string ErrorMessage { get { return _ErrorMessage; } }
        /// <summary>
        /// Stop a Windows service service name
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ServiceName"></param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// A service does not stop instantly, so WaitForStatus method
        /// is used to 'wait' until the service has stopped. If the
        /// caller becomes unresponsive then there may be issues with
        /// the service stopping outside of code.
        /// </remarks>
        public void StopService(string ServiceName)
        {
            ServiceController sc = ServiceController.GetServices().FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceName == ServiceName);
            if (sc == null)
                return;

            if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                try
                {
                    sc.Stop();
                    sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException e)
                {
                    _ErrorMessage = e.Message;
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Start a Windows service by service name
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ServiceName"></param>
        public void StartService(string ServiceName)
        {
            ServiceController sc = ServiceController.GetServices().FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceName == ServiceName);
            if (sc == null)
                return;

            sc.ServiceName = ServiceName;
            if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
            {
                try
                {
                    sc.Start();
                    sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    _ErrorMessage = e.Message;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with WaitForStatus, but my form is infinite frozzen

Comment: Been using this without issues here and never had issues so I have nothing constructive to add.